# How to downgrade AWS SDK in Spring-integration-aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

Is there anyway we can leverage the massaging handler capability that is part of spring-integration-aws-1.1.0-RC1 we just downgrade the AWS SDK version to aws-sdk-core-1.4.x ?

As I would like to integrate with a proprietary CMS application [Hitachi Content Platform], which support old version AWS S3 API (i.e. AWS SDK 1.4.x ).

Meantime I still want do have to leverage the S3MessageHandler for my service call handling. Is there any middle path to the problem.

Note:- The AWS SDK that is part of spring-integration-aws-1.1.0-RC1 is not supported by CMS application.

Answer (score 1):

With upgraded AWD SDK the difference in my case was the Authentication cookie names and few other cookie. These difference was set by the Signer. So in my ClientConfiguration I set the signer to S3SignerType that resolved my issue. See AmazonS3Client registered signer.

```
ClientConfiguration.setSignerOverride("S3SignerType");
```